# Managing React Native 0.44.0 using yarn; dependency issues causing packager to crash

Tags: svg, dependencies, react-native, yarnpkg

As stated I am using yarn as a package manager, and recently upgraded my application to React-Native 0.44.0. My package.json is as follows:

```js
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install crypto --hack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "assert": "^1.4.1",
    "asyncstorage-down": "^3.1.1",
    "braintree": "^1.46.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.1.4",
    "buffer": "^3.6.0",
    "console-browserify": "^1.1.0",
    "constants-browserify": "0.0.1",
    "create-hmac": "^1.1.4",
    "dns.js": "^1.0.1",
    "domain-browser": "^1.1.7",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "firebase": "^3.6.3",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "https-browserify": "0.0.1",
    "jest-haste-map": "^18.1.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "os-browserify": "^0.1.2",
    "path-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.9",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-facebook-login": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-http": "github:tradle/react-native-http#834492d",
    "react-native-level-fs": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "1.5.15",
    "react-native-looped-carousel": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-maps": "0.12.4",
    "react-native-material-kit": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "3.37.0",
    "react-native-svg": ">=5.1.8",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "0.0.3",
    "react-native-tcp": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-twitter-signin": "github:rakannimer/react-native-twitter-signin",
    "react-native-udp": "^1.2.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^3.0.0",
    "readable-stream": "^1.0.33",
    "rn-nodeify": "^6.0.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "timers-browserify": "^1.4.2",
    "tty-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "url": "^0.10.3",
    "vm-browserify": "0.0.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "17.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.1"
  },
  "react-native": {
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "os-browserify",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "os-browserify",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify"
  }
}
```

Running `react-native run-android` succeeds in building the project, but then the packager crashes with te following error:

`` Bundling `index.android.js`  44.9% (327/488), failed.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chrisdock/Desktop/Jdoe/jdoe-redux/node_modules/react-native-svg/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo.android.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:491:33)
    at Module._readSourceCode (/Users/chrisdock/Desktop/Jdoe/jdoe-redux/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:200:29)
    at Module._getCacheProps (/Users/chrisdock/Desktop/Jdoe/jdoe-redux/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:420:29)
    at Module._readFromTransformCache (/Users/chrisdock/Desktop/Jdoe/jdoe-redux/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:376:29)
    at Module.readCached (/Users/chrisdock/Desktop/Jdoe/jdoe-redux/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:363:25)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/chrisdock/Desktop/Jdoe/jdoe-redux/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:167:29) ``

I'm not sure why the packager is looking for nested dependencies instead of in node_modules/react-native, or why yarn doesn't just install the nested dependencies if that's what it needs to do.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I ended up just using npm with shrinkwrap :/ not as fast but at least it works